# removing specific overlays from mapview

Tags: android, android-mapview, overlays

my problem is as follows.

I am creating multiple itemized overlays. (because every overlay gets a different drawable)
I customized the itemized overlay class, but when i add it to the mapview overlays, the class is transformed into an overlay class.
to make it worse i got 3 classes creating overlays on the same map. each class represents an item on the map with it's own intelligence behind it.

the problem i now have is that i want to remove an overlay, but i can not be sure that the index i inserted it on, is also the index it has when i try to remove it. (the other classes might have inserted an overlay in the mean time)

the classes are self updating, so i do not want a solution that fires an update or delete event from the main class. (the whole point is to add a class and forget about it)

so my question would be: how can i identify which layer is which when i want to call a remove on that layer. i think the information is available, but i do not know how to get to it.
this is the code i am using to add the overlay

```android
 OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(p,myNaam ,myOmschrijving );

    LocationOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(drawable, myContext);

    LocationOverlay.SetLocation(i,overlayitem);

    myOverlays.add(LocationOverlay);
```

Comment: the question is still open, but i might have found a workaround by using the setmarker method. still testing

Answer (score 1):

You can set a certain integer as a position for every overlays
something like that :

```
mapView.getOverlays().add(0,myScaleBarOverlay);
```

and when you want ro remove this call:

```
mapView.getOverlays().remove(0);
mapView.invalidate();
```

Regard

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to remove specific layer. You can remove an **overlay** specified by it's reference (e.g. **myOverlay**).

```
LocationOverlay myOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(drawable, myContext); //`you forgot the name of variable`

mapView.getOverlays().remove(myOverlay);
```

Comment: the problem is that i do not have a reference. i did not forget the variable, it is declared elsewhere. myoverlays is the list of overlays that you add an itemizedoverlay to. so the real question is, how can i get a reference when i have none? I think i would have to inspect the contents of the overlays somehow to decide which is which, or keep a list of overlays. but again, how do i get a list of overlays, if i do not know how to refer to an overlay, once it is inserted into the mapview

Comment: Why don't you have one? Don't you create this overlay yourself? Is the code created by someone else? If not, you can create your reference (just keep it in the class scope, not function scope if you want to use it otuside the function). If you say that you declared the reference elsewhere, than this line `LocationOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(drawable, myContext);` is corrupt, because it assumes that LocationOverlay is the name of variable and you probably meant the name of `LocationOverlay` class.

Comment: I understand your confusion. I removed the code, because it was not helping.
What happens is that when you add an overlay to the collection on the mapview, it is like putting a ball in a bowl full of balls. you might get the same one when you draw a ball out of the bowl, but you can not be sure without exmamining it. someone might have shaken the bowl so to speak. you input a specific ball, but you get a random ball back, so i need to be able to compare the balls.

Comment: Post your code Please (whole MapActivity) , because from what i can tell you're just ignoring the fact that you can remove overlay by reference (I do it in my app and it works like a charn). I need to see the way you try to remove it, just post the whole activity